# How to change check/uncheck listbox when click checkbox in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

I'm usig div and id of css to check and uncheck in checkbox, but my source cannot as expected

**step 1**: as default checkbox is uncheck and listbox is disable

**step 2**: when i check checkbox, listbox is enable

**step 3**: back step 1, if i uncheck checkbox, listbox is disable

my souce:

```js
$('#parnerCheck2').click(function() {
  $('#partnerName').prop("checked", false).prop("disabled", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">Partner</th>
  <td colspan="1" style="margin-top: 4px;">
    <input id="parnerCheck2" name="parnerCheck" type="checkbox" value="0" /><span>PARTNER</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select id="partnerName" name="partnerName">
      <option value="" selected>Choose One</option>
      <option>01 - Elite</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

How to fix the problem as my description? thank a lot

Comment: If you disable, do you also wish to unselect the selected value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You where almost there. You can set disabled property on the list box with the checked value of the checkbox, prefixed with the not operator `!` to reverse the value, to get the result you want.

```js
$('#parnerCheck2').click(function() {
  $('#partnerName').prop("disabled", !$(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">Partner</th>
  <td colspan="1" style="margin-top: 4px;">
    <input id="parnerCheck2" name="parnerCheck" type="checkbox" value="0" /><span>PARTNER</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select id="partnerName" name="partnerName" disabled>
      <option value="" selected>Choose One</option>
      <option>01 - Elite</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

This would also work.

```html
<body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        //set initial state.
        $('#partnerName').prop('disabled', true);

        $('#partnerCheck').click(function() {
            if ($('#partnerCheck').is(':checked')) {
                $('#partnerName').prop('disabled', false);
            }
        });
        });
    </script>
 
 
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Partner</th>
        <td colspan="1" style="margin-top: 4px;">
            <input id="partnerCheck" name="partnerCheck" type="checkbox" value="0" /><span>PARTNER</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="partnerName" name="partnerName">
                <option value="" selected >Choose One</option>
                <option>01 - Elite</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</body>
```